# Laravel 4 doesn't decode post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and I came to an issue that I was not able to solve.

I have a WebService made with Laravel 4.2.

This WS receives a POST request with several fields, one of then is EMAIL.

Payload (POST ENCTYPE multipart/form-data)

```
name=John&password=1234&email=email%40server.com&surname=Lopes
```

When I try a validation, it always fails on EMAIL validation rule saying that the email is invalid.

Rules on Model:

```
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|max:50',
    'surname' => 'max:100',
    'chatusername' => 'max:64',
    'photo' => 'max:245',
    'password' => 'required|max:64',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:245',
    'accesstoken' => 'max:64',
    'remember_token' => 'max:64'
];
```

On Webservice

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
```

If I debug and print this field, I get the email field url encoded.

```
email%40server.com
```

So, the rule fails because laravel isn't decoding fields before doing validation.

I'm doing something wrong??

Comment: What are your validation rules  in your user model User:$rules and the payload?

Comment: thats weird your @ sing gets encoded to %40 either something is wrong the <input field> or the <form> part of it, as i a believe i dont wana mislead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**       Default. All characters are encoded before sent
>   (spaces are converted to "+" symbols, and special
>   characters are converted to ASCII HEX values)
>   **multipart/form-data**   No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control
>       **text/plain**    Spaces are converted to "+" symbols, but no special characters are encoded

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

read these maybe a bit of help!

Comment: You're right... it happens that the problem was the client (an iOS app) and not the server (laravel). Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As Pelevet suggests, try adjusting your model rules to:

```
public static $rules = array(
  'email'                 => 'required|email',
);
```